# I created a sprite in over 50 random places in my code and only the last sprite has the animation. How can I make all of them be animated?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I created a sprite in over 50 random places in my code and only the last sprite has the animation. I am trying to create a dungeon crawler game, and I dont want to initialized 50 different sprites for 1 aspect of the game.

I used `this.spikes = this.physics.add.sprite(drawX, drawY, "spikes")`; in a loop to create over 50 in random places, then in the update function I tried `this.spikes.anims.play("spikes",true);`. I have attached all of my code here.

```
  const map = getMap();
  //Declare variables at the top of code
  let random;
  //Create phaser settings
  let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: {
                y: 0
            },
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
  };
  //Create phaser game
  const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
  
  function preload() {
    //Preloading assets needed
    this.load.spritesheet("player", "assets/sprites/player.png", {
        frameWidth: 16,
        frameHeight: 30
    });
    this.load.spritesheet("spikes", "assets/sprites/spikes.png", {
        frameWidth: 16,
        frameHeight: 16
    });
  
    this.load.image("floor", "assets/tiles/floor.png");
    this.load.image("floor_1", "assets/tiles/floor_1.png");
    this.load.image("floor_2", "assets/tiles/floor_2.png");
    this.load.image("floor_3", "assets/tiles/floor_3.png");
    this.load.image("floor_4", "assets/tiles/floor_4.png");
    this.load.image("floor_5", "assets/tiles/floor_5.png");
    this.load.image("floor_6", "assets/tiles/floor_6.png");
    this.load.image("floor_7", "assets/tiles/floor_7.png");
  
    this.load.image("wallLeft", "assets/tiles/wallLeft.png");
    this.load.image("wallRight", "assets/tiles/wallRight.png");
    this.load.image("wallBottom", "assets/tiles/wallBottom.png");
    this.load.image("wallTop", "assets/tiles/wallTop.png");
    this.load.image("bg", "assets/tiles/bg.png");
  }
  
  function create() {
    //Spawn player with restrictions
    this.cameras.main.setBackgroundColor('#ffffff');
    this.spawnPlayer = (x, y) => {
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(x, y, "player");
        this.player.body.setGravityY(0);
        this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.wall);
        this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);
        this.cameras.main.setZoom(2);
  
        this.player.score = 0;
        this.scoreText = this.add.text(0, 0, "Score: " + this.player.score, {
            fill: "#000000",
            fontSize: "20px",
            fontFamily: "Arial Black"
        }).setScrollFactor(0);
    };
    //Declare Static objects
    this.wall = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    this.bg = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    this.floor = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    //Generate Map
    let mapArr = map.split('.');
    let drawX = 0;
    let drawY = 0;
    mapArr.forEach(row => {
        drawX = 0;
        for (let a = 0; a < row.length; a++) {
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 0) + 1);
            if (row.charAt(a) == 0) {
                this.bg.create(drawX, drawY, "bg");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 1) {
                this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor");
                this.spawnPlayer(drawX, drawY);
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 7) {
                if (random == 1) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_1");
                } else if (random == 2) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_2");
                } else if (random == 3) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_3");
                } else if (random == 4) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_4");
                } else if (random == 5) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_5");
                } else if (random == 6) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_6");
                } else if (random == 7) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_7");
                } else if (random == 8) {
                    this.spikes = this.physics.add.sprite(drawX, drawY, "spikes");
                } else {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor");
                }
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 8) {
                this.wall.create(drawX, drawY, "wallBottom");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 9) {
                this.wall.create(drawX, drawY, "wallTop");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 6) {
                this.wall.create(drawX, drawY, "wallRight");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 5) {
                this.wall.create(drawX, drawY, "wallLeft");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 4) {
                this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor");
            }
            drawX += 16;
        }
        drawY += 16;
    });
    //Generate player above map images
    this.player.depth = 100;
  
    //Create animations
    this.anims.create({
        key: "walk",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {
            start: 4,
            end: 7,
            first: 4
        }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });
    this.anims.create({
        key: "stand",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {
            start: 0,
            end: 3,
            first: 0
        }),
        frameRate: 1,
        repeat: -1
    });
    this.anims.create({
        key: "spikes",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('spikes', {
            start: 0,
            end: 3,
            first: 0
        }),
        frameRate: 1,
        repeat: -1
    });
    //Declare Keys used in  game
    this.key_W = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W);
    this.key_A = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A);
    this.key_S = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
    this.key_D = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D);
    this.key_Q = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.Q);
  }
  
  function update() {
    //Apply animations
    this.spikes.anims.play("spikes", true);
    //Moving player
    if (this.key_A.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(-200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
        this.player.flipX = true;
    } else if (this.key_D.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
        this.player.flipX = false;
    } else if (this.key_W.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityY(-200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
    } else if (this.key_S.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityY(200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
    } else {
        this.player.anims.play("stand", true);
        this.player.setVelocityX(0);
        this.player.setVelocityY(0);
    }
  }
  //END OF GAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the spikes are not working. The problem is that you are calling the `play` function on the ***group***, you depending on your version the currect function name is `playAnimation`

The solution is to delete the line `this.spikes.anims.play("spikes", true);` in the `update` function, AND adding this line in the `create` function

```
this.spikes.playAnimation('spikes');
```

This should solve the problem, *if the problem has to do with the `spike` sprites.*

**Update:**

1. Create the `this.spikes` as a `Group`

   ```
   ...
   this.spikes = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
   ...
   ```
2. And change the line:

   ```
   this.spikes = this.physics.add.sprite(drawX, drawY, "spikes");
   ```

   to

   ```
   this.spikes.create(drawX, drawY, "spikes");
   ```
3. Then add the `playAnimation` call at the end of the `create` function

   ```
   this.spikes.playAnimation('spikes');
   ```

Comment: I tried what you said. I put this.spikes.playAnimation('spikes'); at the bottom of the create function, and my phaser screen froze. Everything in the map loads, but the screen is frozen (the spike animation wont even play when frozen. If you want to see the updated code, https://replit.com/@JackF99/test-2d-array#script.js. Am I able to create the animation and play the animation in the same function?

Comment: @JackF99 well the problem is, that you didn't create the `this.spikes` as the other tiles (like `this.floor`, `this.wall`, ...), check my updated answer for a solution

Comment: @JackF99 ps.: you are using phaser version `v3.14.0` the current version `v3.55.2` is. Use https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js for the current version.